# Are raw commands available in StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Is there any functionality in StackExchange.Redis that allows you to execute raw commands directly? Like I'd provide a string with the command, e.g. (hypothetical code below):

```
conn.Send("ZADD mysortedset 1 john");
```

I know there are methods available for just about every command including `ZADD`, but that's not the point.

Comment: Just to say: this has now changed, and there is an API for this. See updated answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The introduction of "modules" made this a lot more relevant; this API now exists in `Execute(...)`. See: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/04/stackexchangeredis-and-redis-40-modules.html

---

Previously:

Not currently, and I'd be dubious of the benefit. In particular, doing this wouldn't allow correct routing on sharded instances (twemproxy, redis-cluster, etc), wouldn't allow renamed command-map usage, and wouldn't allow binary keys / values to be used. It would also allow very risky and concept-breaking commands to be used inappropriately, such as `select`, `watch`/`multi`/`exec`, blocking-pops `brpop`/`blpop`/`brpoplpush` - all of which would be catastrophic to the multiplexer (well, `select` isn't a biggie, as it can just be configured such that `Send` leaves the db undefined - the code for that already exists thanks to some similar examples). It would also expose dangerous commands that should *never need to be used* from a general library: `debug segfault`, `client pause`, etc - again, all *very bad ideas*.

But sure, in theory it *could be done*... but I would *really* want to see a compelling reason to offset the many problems above.

At the moment, the most exposed way to execute ad-hoc commands is via `ScriptEvaluate` - it would involve writing Lua, of course.

Comment: Here's a use case: I would like to send a DEBUG OBJECT Command to Redis to see how big a value is given a key.

Comment: @Daniel tbh I thought we already exposed DEBUG OBJECT - pretty sure we use that in "opserver" for db analytics, but: it also exist in the new Execute API, released about a week ago; http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/04/stackexchangeredis-and-redis-40-modules.html

Comment: im looking for zrange and zadd in stackexchange.redis but i cant find any result. can you say how can i do that? i was looking for running raw commands that found this

Comment: @virtouso look for the `SortedSet*` methods